# Multiples tables side by side

Tags: tables, positioning

I'm trying to put 8 tables 4 in one line and the other 4 below them, but for some reason it doesn't result as I want.

I want the tables in the following order

J3 J2 J1 J0
K3 K2 K1 K0

and each one with its caption

but I get

J3 J3caption K3 K3caption
J2 J2caption K2 K2caption
...

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %J3 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla J3}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %K3 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla K3}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %J2 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla J2}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %K2 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla K2}
    }
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %J1 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla J1}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %K1 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla K1}
    }
\end{minipage} 

\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %J0 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla J0}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            %K0 table%
        \end{tabular}
        \selectfont\textit{Tabla K0}
    }
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

There must be some little detail that I'm missing. As I'm new to LaTeX, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty line represents a paragraph break, which will necessarily stack things vertically (on top of one another) rather than horizontally (next to one another). Here's an alternative view on it, using the [`supcaption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \subcaptionbox{J3}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      J3
    \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{J2}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      J2
    \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{J1}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      J1
    \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{J0}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      J0
    \end{tabular}}%

  \bigskip

  \subcaptionbox{K3}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      K3
    \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{K2}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      K2
    \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{K1}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      K1
    \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{K0}[.25\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      K0
    \end{tabular}}%

  \caption{A set of 8 tables.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The interface `\subcaptionbox{<sub-caption>}[<width>]{<stuff>}` (minimalized) sets `<stuff>` in a box of width `<width>` that has a numbered sub-caption `<sup-caption>`. If you don't want a numbered sub-caption, use `\subcaptionbox*`.

Comment: thanks, that works great, but I have a question, whats the function of the % at the end of some lines?

Comment: @JoseMiguel: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)